# Clear the contents of multiple TextBox objects in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have following XAML in WPF

```
<Canvas>
    <WrapPanel x:Name="TimeTableMainWrapPanel" Canvas.Left="109" Canvas.Top="195" Height="601" Width="745>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtFirstLctrTime"  Height="24" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="115"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtSecondLctrTime" Height="23" Canvas.Left="594" TextWrapping="Wrap" Canvas.Top="189" Width="115"/>

        <WrapPanel x:Name="TimeTableSubWrapPanel" Canvas.Left="109" Canvas.Top="195" Height="601" Width="745">
            <WrapPanel x:Name="FirstLecture" Background="#00F0F8FF" Height="392" Width="133" Margin="0,0,10,0">
                <TextBox x:Name="txtMondayFirstLctr" Width="133" Margin="0" Height="30" FontSize="13" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtTuesdayFirstLctr" Width="133" Margin="0,38,0,0" Height="30" FontSize="13" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
            </WrapPanel>

            <WrapPanel x:Name="SecondLecture" Canvas.Top="220" Background="#00F0F8FF" Canvas.Left="270" Height="466" Width="133" Margin="8,0,10,0">
                <TextBox x:Name="txtMondaySecondLctr" Width="133" Margin="0,38,0,0" Height="30" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtTuesdaySecondLctr" Width="133" Margin="0,38,0,0" Height="30" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
            </WrapPanel>
        </WrapPanel>
    </WrapPanel>
</Canvas>
```

I wanted to **clear content of all textbox on button click.** And for that I am doing

```
var firsttextboxes = this.FirstLecture.Children.OfType<TextBox>();
var secondtextboxes = this.SecondLecture.Children.OfType<TextBox>();

foreach (var textbox in firsttextboxes)
{
    textbox.Clear();
}

foreach (var textbox in secondtextboxes)
{
    textbox.Clear();
}
```

Is there any better way of doing this, instead of using multiple `foreach` loops?

Also how do I enter one value in each `TextBox` and move to next?

I am trying the code below, but it is inserting the same value in all `TextBox` objects:

```
foreach(var a in firsttextboxes ) 
{ 
    foreach(var b in Text) 
    { 
        a.Text = b 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Union and combine all the sources. Then foreach over allTextboxes.

```
var allTextboxes = firsttextboxes
                    .Union(secondtextboxes)
                    .Union(thirdtextboxes);
                    //And so on
foreach (var textbox in allTextboxes )
{
    textbox.Clear();
}
```

Another approach would be looking at the visual tree to find out all the TextBoxes within the parent `WrapPanel` and clear them.

Comment: One last ques, if i have Five textbox and five values how will i append one value each in respective Textbox using foreach? I trie like     foreach(var a in Timetable) 
          { 
            foreach(var b in Text) 
               { 
                  a.Text = b 
                } 
           }     BUt it is inserting same value in all Textbox

Comment: @Richa You're doing it wrong. If you do this way, it will be a maintenance problem for you. Please look at `DataBinding`. Create a ViewModel class which exposes (those 5)properties and bind respective property to the `TextBox`. Then implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in ViewModel, so that when the property is updated, TextBox will be automatically updated. Search for "Wpf Mvvm databinding"

Answer (score 1):

I have created a `Generic` method to do the same. `PerformOperationOnVisualTreeControl` method accepts parent control and an `Action method to define your operation.

```
public static void PerformOperationOnVisualTreeControl<T>(Visual myVisual, Action<T> action)
{
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(myVisual); i++)
        {
            var childVisual = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(myVisual, i);
            if (typeof(T) == childVisual.GetType())
            {
                T control = (T)System.Convert.ChangeType(childVisual, typeof(T));
                action(control);
            }

            PerformOperationOnVisualTreeControl<T>(childVisual, action);
        }
}
```

You can call `PerformOperationOnVisualTreeControl` method like below

Update : I have created a `Queue` to update all the `TextBox` with database values. `Queue` will `Dequeue` value one by one and update the `TextBox`

```
var dbValues = new Queue<int>(Enumerable.Range(1, 5));
PerformOperationOnVisualTreeControl<TextBox>(this.TimeTableSubWrapPanel, (control) =>
{
    control.Clear();
    if (dbValues.Count > 0)
    {
        control.Text = dbValues.Dequeue().ToString();
    }
});
```

Comment: @Richa sorry it was a typo, i have updated the answer,

Comment: Works good. Thanks A lot . Can you help in second part of question?

Comment: you can pass any action which you want to perform on a particular control.

Comment: Can you explain more what you want achieve in the 2nd part

Comment: If i have 5 textbox and i fetch 5 number from DB, i want to append first value in first textbox and so on . So say i have 5 value fetched from Db 1,2,3,4,5 so first texbox should have value 1,second texbox value 2 and s on

Comment: What issue are you getting, Please explain

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74554/discussion-between-richa-and-vimal-ck).

Answer (score 0):

```
void ClearDescendantTextBoxes(Control ctrl)
{
    foreach (Control child in ctrl.Controls)
        if (child is TextBox)
            child.Text = "";
        else ClearDescendantTextBoxes(child);
}
```

(This is for winforms. But you can probably fix it easily for wpf.)

Answer (score 0):

In regards to MVVM, I would Create a command for the button that is responsible for clearing the textboxes.

I would then implement the command by setting the observable properties that should be bound to the textboxes to null.

This removes the code-behind that typically grows into a maintenance nightmare / God-class.

Answer (score 0):

var allTextboxes = this.mainpan.Children.OfType();

```
        foreach (var textbox in allTextboxes)
        {
            textbox.Clear();
        }
        var allTextboxe = this.mainpan.Children.OfType<ComboBox>();
        foreach (var textbox in allTextboxe)
        {
            textbox.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
```

Comment: This answer could be better explained, especially since this answer is 5+ years later than the original question. Does it add anything that the other answers did not? Please elaborate if possible so that anyone who comes across this in the future will have more context.